# How to create a page in WordPress with PHP and without using an admin panel or creating an HTML file?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a page like this(without using the admin panel or creating an HTML file):
example.com/something
but I don't want to create a "something" page in the WordPress admin panel.
So I have to create a page by PHP.
I've used these codes in function.php:

```
if(false !== strpos($url,'something')) {
    echo 'something exists!';
}
```

Now when the page loads it shows "something exists!" on the page for a moment and then loads the "404" page.
Please tell me how can I avoid the "404" page to load on my content.
Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but this is a question impossible to answer. It is by far too broad. Why would one want to use a CMS system (wordpress) only to then _not_ use it? That makes no sense. If there is some strange reason then please say so. I expect much more relevant details to emerge once you explain what it actually is you want to do.

Comment: I have answer using a dynamic router approach. Gimme 10 mins to post answer. @arkascha sometimes you need to create urls for webhook endpoints or other methods that you may not want to have a page in the cms which users can see.

Comment: @joshmoto For that one simply implements a rewriting exception. But this is guessing, the OP did not explain what the situation is. Which is why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you want an accessible url in wordpress with out creating a page or post in the database then you could use a Dynamic Router plugin or php class.

### [`DynamicRouter.lib.php`](https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/3f8831f457ca0526dbc80d97a9b43394)

We have developed a PHP class lib which makes creating dynamic page urls in wordpress easy.

Here is the `DynamicRouter.lib.php` class file with no dependancies...

[https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/DynamicRouter.lib.php](https://gist.github.com/joshmoto/3f8831f457ca0526dbc80d97a9b43394)

### How to use `DynamicRouter.lib.php`

First add this lib file to your theme, in a folder called `lib` for example.

Then in your `functions.php` require this class lib once...

```
// class libraries
require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/DynamicRouter.lib.php');
```

Then after this required lib in your functions (not before) you can begin creating dynamic urls without creating physical pages/posts in the wordpress cms.

Now create a function (example below) to create and configure your dynamic routes.

```
// register custom url routes
function register_routes () {

    // make sure our DynamicRouter class exists
    if(!class_exists('DynamicRouter')) return false;

    // create page url /something
    DynamicRouter::create(
        '^something$',
        'router.php',
        'Something | ',
        [
            'post_name' => 'something'
        ]
    );

    // create page url /some-other-thing
    DynamicRouter::create(
        '^some-other-thing$',
        'router.php',
        'Some Other Thing | ',
        [
            'post_name' => 'some-other-thing'
        ]
    );

    // create page url /parent-thing/child-thing
    DynamicRouter::create(
        '^parent-thing/child-thing$',
        'router.php',
        'Child Thing | ',
        [
            'post_name' => 'child-thing'
        ]
    );

    // handle our page routes
    DynamicRouter::handle();

}
```

Then also make sure you run the above function in your `functions.php`.

```
// register the routes
register_routes();
```

Then create a php called `router.php` in the root of your theme folder to handle routes by `argument` `post_name`, using this code below...

```
<?php
/**
 * router.php handler
 */

// current route array
$route = DynamicRouter::getCurrentRoute();

// handle custom routes 
switch ($route['arguments']['post_name']) {

    case 'something':
        
        // do your stuff here for url: example.com/something
        // get other custom php template or do functions
        var_dump('something');
        break;

    case 'some-other-thing':

        // do your stuff here for url: example.com/some-other-thing
        // get other custom php template or do functions
        var_dump('some-other-thing');
        break;

    case 'child-thing':

        // do your stuff here for url: example.com/parent-thing/child-thing
        // get other custom php template or do functions
        var_dump('parent-thing/child-thing');
        break;

    default:

        return false;

}
```

### Very important, update permalinks

This is **very important**, none of the above code will work until you update the `permalinks` in your wordpress admin settings...

[image]

Simply go to the `Permalinks` section as shown above and hit the `Save Changes` button. You **do not** need to modify any of the current permalink settings, just simply hit the `Save Changes` button.

Now all of your custom url routes (as per example above) will work and not return a `404` page.

- [example.com/something](https://example.com)
- [example.com/some-other-thing](https://example.com)
- [example.com/parent-thing/child-thing](https://example.com)

These urls will now do what ever you've configured in `router.php` (in your theme folder).

### Final very important end notes

- If you make any changes to your `register_routes()` php configuration code, your new changes will not work until you re-save your permalinks again.
- If you deploy your local or staging environment to a live/production environment, then also make sure you re-save your permalinks in settings to apply latest configurations in your `register_routes()` function.