# Wordpress connecting dynamic php pages

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, themes, permalinks

I create a page called test (https://mywp.com/test) I'd like to connect an external PHP to fill the content of the page. The PHP file is called page-test.php and it is at the root of the WordPress theme.
I'd like to do that without using "Theme Name:   New Theme", and having to change the Page Attributes on the page.
How can I link the permalink https://mywp.com/test to open the PHP file when called?
Thanks

Comment: This should do the trick https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64920244/how-to-create-a-page-in-wordpress-with-php-and-without-using-an-admin-panel-or-c/64921035#64921035

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I just want a way to link the file to the page I can create both manually, generate the page on wp and create the file manually with the content, that's not a problem. in short, I just want when opening the URL (hyperlink generated by wp) open the specific page in PHP

Answer (score 1):

You can Create a page in your wordpress, then you can include the code using iframe like this

```
<iframe src="https://mywp.com/wp-content/themes/YOUR_THEME/page-test.php" width="100%" height="300" style="border:1px solid black;">
</iframe>
```